# How to remove potential <p> tags surrounding URLs in a string via PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex or way to be able to find URLS and if they are wrapped by paragraph tags, remove the paragraph tags and leave the rest of content as is.

**Example**

```
<p>Good morning,</p>

<p>Please watch the following video</p>

<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssssssssssssssss</p>

<p>Hope you enjoyed it.</p>
```

**Desired Result**

```
<p>Good morning,</p>

<p>Please watch the following video</p>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssssssssssssssss

<p>Hope you enjoyed it.</p>
```

So basically, I want to the URLs (not **anchor** tags, just plain urls surrounded by **paragraph** tags to have the pargraph tags stripped from content / string.

Any solution?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How is this content generated? If with PHP, you can think of applying [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on url before generating the content.

Comment: Yes, it's a php generated content.

Comment: Show us your code to generate above content. `$content = $somecontent . stripe_tags($url) . $somecontent;`

Comment: But I do not know where the URL will be, the content can have multiple links.

Comment: ok. then regex is better option. seems like you are scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<\w+>((((ftp|http|https):\/\/)|(\/)|(..\/))(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)<\/\w+>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU8oQ2/1)

PHP:

```
$re = "/<\\w+>((((ftp|http|https):\\/\\/)|(\\/)|(..\\/))(\\w+:{0,1}\\w*@)?(\\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\\/|\\/([\\w#!:.?+=&%@!\\-\\/]))?)<\\/\\w+>/"; 
$str = "<h1>Something:Hello!</h1>\"\n\n<p>Good morning,</p>\n\n<p>Please watch the following video</p>\n\n<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssssssssssssssss</p>\n\n<p>Hope you enjoyed it.</p>"; 
$subst = "$1"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Can you please show me a sample example how to replace the regex above? e.g. replace it by what? if I use preg_replace( regex, ?

Comment: Here is at least one string, which is obviously not an URL, but does pass the above regex: "<h1>Something:Hello!</h1>"

Comment: and this one should pass, no? "<p class="my">http://www.google.com</p>", but it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

A rough checking for URL would be suffice for this situation.

**Regex:** `<p>(?=https?.*www.*\.com)(.*)<\/p>`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1` or `$1` which have URL captured in first capturing group.

**Explanation:**

- `(?=https?.*www.*\.com)` lookahead if URL is present by checking for `https`, `www` and `.com` and characters between them
- `(.*)` captures the whole URL in first capturing group.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS6sJ9/1)**

Comment: Excuse me, so If I use preg_replace() what should I replace it with? I am new to regex, sorry.

Comment: @AhmedWP: Sorry for replying late. I guess you have a working solution now. My regex will fit in Tim's php code.